# Draw kdeplots for two variables using seaborn in python

Tags: python, seaborn

I am using the below code to draw two kdeplots for a variable:

```
income_df = attrition_df[['Annual Income','Terminated']]
income_left = income_df.loc[income_df['Terminated'] == 1]
income_stayed = income_df.loc[income_df['Terminated'] == 0]
x = np.array(income_left['Annual Income'].values)
y = np.array(income_stayed['Annual Income'].values)
ax = sns.kdeplot(x,y, shade=True)
```

But I am getting an error as:

ValueError: The number of observations must be larger than the number of variables.

I do not understand why this error is being thrown and how to draw the plots. Can someone please help me regarding this.
Intention is to get something like :
[image]

Comment: Are you intending to draw two separate univariate kde plots (what you say), or a bivariate kde plot (what your code is doing)?

Comment: hi @mwaskom,
Intention is to draw kdeplot of Annual Income across two different categories of Terminated(1/0). I have updated the question with the desired output.Please let me know what do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you want to plot two kde plots of different quantities.

```
ax = sns.kdeplot(x)
sns.kdeplot(y, ax=ax)
```